# (Mac OS PF) Redirect outgoing UDP traffice to specific ip:port

Tags: mac-osx, redirect, pf, ip-forwarding

I'm having some trouble getting my head around how PF works in Mac OS. I have been doing a lot of research on the topic but just cannot find the solution (although I can find many other very similar questions without an answer).

My goal is to redirect an outgoing packet that uses UDP port (21928) being sent to a multicast address (225.0.0.37) to a different UDP port (6010) of the same multicast address before it leaves my interface.

If this is not possible, redirecting the port (21928) to the address 192.168.0.20:6010 would be the next best thing, however the original multicast address is preferable.

Now as far as I can tell, you cannot use PF rules on outgoing packets, however you can redirect those packets to the loopback address and then perform rules this way.

```
rdr pass inet proto udp from any to 225.0.0.37 port 21928 -> 225.0.0.37 port 6010
pass out on en4 route-to lo0 proto udp from en4 to 225.0.0.37 port 21928 keep state
```

These are the current rules I'm playing with, and in wireshark I can see that when PF is active, the packet enters the loopback interface, however other than this nothing happens (when i disable PF, the packet leaves as originally intended on 225.0.0.37:21928 indicating that PF is doing something when enabled at least).

Additionally I have enabled this command:

```
sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be very much appreciated.